# Exporting Data to Excel file From Sql Server 2014 using SSIS 2012

Tags: sql-server, excel, visual-studio-2012, ssis, data-warehouse

I am using windows 8.1, office 2013, Visual Studio 2013, SQL Server 2014 and SSIS 12.0

I have a data flow which has OLE DB source, Data Conversion And Excel Destination.
My OLEDB Source
[image]
Data Conversion
[image]
I have create a Excel file StudentInfo.xls in (C:\XX) folder and make a connection 
[image]

Everything is OK, but when I execute it I giving me the following errors:

> Error: 0xC0209303 at DynamicExcel, Connection manager "Excel Connection Manager": The requested OLE DB provider
>   Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 is not registered. If the 64-bit driver is not
>   installed, run the package in 32-bit mode. Error code: 0x00000000.
>       An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered".
>
> Error: 0xC020801C at Data Flow Task, Excel Destination [24]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The
>   AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel
>   Connection Manager" failed with error code 0xC0209303.  There may be
>   error messages posted before this with more information on why the
>   AcquireConnection method call failed.

This link ([Switch package from 64bit to 32bit](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2012/09/swtich-package-from-64bit-to-32bit.html)) led me to change the `Run64BitRuntime` property to **False**.

After changing the property, I am now getting a different set of errors:

> Error: 0xC0202009 at DynamicExcel, Connection manager "Excel
>   Connection Manager": SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB
>   error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is
>   available.  Source: "Microsoft JET Database Engine"  Hresult:
>   0x80004005  Description: "The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot
>   open the file ''.  It is already opened exclusively by another user,
>   or you need permission to view its data.".
>
> Error: 0xC020801C at Data Flow Task, Excel Destination [24]: SSIS
>   Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The
>   AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel
>   Connection Manager" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be
>   error messages posted before this with more information on why the
>   AcquireConnection method call failed.

Comment: it's probably an issue with permissions on the folder you're trying to write to (if it's not the obvious issue; the file being opened exclusively and/or write permissions on the file itself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've the same message, I have an SSIS project on visual studio 2010, I read a file.xls on that page, in my project VS 2010 has not any problem when I tried to store some query results to excel file, throw me a 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' the provider is not registered on the local machine', I fixed that problem next following this steps,

1.-Open IIS

2.-Change the appPool on Advanced Settings

3.-true to enable to 32-bit application.

and that's all

ps.I changed Configuration Manager to X86 on Active Solution Platform

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. How I resolved it was:

1. Open SSIS
2. Go to DEBUG
3. Click and open My Project Properties
4. Go under Configuration Properties/Debugging
5. Select False under Run64BitRuntime.
6. Apply the changes

After I did this I was able to run the packages without any errors.